# sed regex: end of string or forward slash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a mapping file `(mapping.txt)` with contents such as:

```
/incoming
/incoming/
/incoming-foo
/incoming-foo/
```

Using sed and regex and want to match (then delete) only the first two lines using the following:

```
sed -i "/\\^/incoming\/?$/d" /mapping.txt
```

However, it is not working.

Basically, I want to strictly match on `/incoming` or `/incoming/` but nothing else.

Any help you guys could provide would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternative regex delimiter in `sed` with `-r` option:

```
sed -r '\#^/incoming/?$#d' file
/incoming-foo
/incoming-foo/
```

Or else with more escaping:

```
sed -r '/^\/incoming\/?$/d' file
```

On OSX (BSD) sed use:

```
sed -E '\#^/incoming/?$#d' file
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer pointed me in the right direction and I finally got it working.

Comment: Ended up using: `sed -ri "/^\/incoming\/?$/d" mapping.txt`

Answer (score 2):

`grep` as an alternative :

```
grep -vE '^/incoming/?$' file
```

this will "remove" the first two lines. If you want to write the output back to your file, you could:

```
grep -vE '^/incoming/?$' file > foo && mv foo file
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to play around with grep as an alternative.